# Can we get people to fill in tag wikis when they create a new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki-excerpt

Orphaned Tag Wikis are sad. They hang around, shambling, and groaning and wait... that's zombies. Or maybe teenagers.

What *does* happen in many cases is they can be ambiguous, get misused, and on some larger sites end up needing many man hours of cleanup.

On the other hand, people who create a tag ought to know what it's for. We can change them later. If its a new user, it also ensures the user's put some thought into it, and lets people review it better. Making them write at least an excerpt, that's peer reviewed. In short, can we make sure that the *need* and goal of any new tag is clearly stated when its created?

Comment: Agreed! Tags are important but then they should not come in abundance

Comment: @random This is an entirely different question then the old you closed it as. They're not duplicates.

Comment: How so? Both ask to have a system of where new tags aren't created without tag wiki info added with them. But this one starts off on something else having to do with orphan tag wikis

Answer (score 0):

Let's presume I want to create a tag, X, for a product I have just downloaded and want to use to do Y. I have no clue how X works but still want to do Y. Yet, since it is quite new, there is no tag yet.

How do you thing I would fill the excerpt? Most of the time that would be a blatant copy of the site of whom created product X. Is that useful? Maybe just a little, but not really.

Letting 'a random user' write the excerpt will most likely not be very helpful and may even cause harm when he doesn't fully understand what X is.